# webClient response using bodyToFlux method merging all the received response instead separating it out

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, spring-reactive, spring5

1. I am using ParallelFlux for running many task.
2. but when i am receiving webClient response using bodyToFlux method its merging all the output response instead of getting one by one.
3. i want the output should be one by one not single string, is there any other method instead of bodyToFLux  need to use.

   request method:

   ```
       Flux<String> responsePost = webClient.build()
                               //removed get,url and retrieve here                             
                               .bodyToFlux(String.class);

                   responsePost.subscribe(s -> {
                       //display response
                       });
   ```

   response method:

   ```
       public ParallelFlux<String> convertListToMap() {
                 //created list of string str

               return Flux.fromIterable(str)
                       .parallel(3)
                       .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                       .map( s -> {
                   //some logic here
               });
          }
   ```

   output:

   ```
       parallel fulx reponse: springwebfluxparellelExample
   ```

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and it is not merging it until you call subscribe. Why are you subscribing?

Comment: changed the format, subscribing it for checking the response.

Comment: You should not subscribe unless you are the consumer. Usually the sonsumer is the calling client.

Comment: yes, but here i wrote the example and wanted to know how parallel flux work and how we can get the out put as list not as a single string on webclient. is there any other way i can try?

Comment: i got one solution instead of returning flux<String> create on ResponseBody class with variable want to return it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here instead of returning ParallelFlux create an
   ResponseBody class with variable you want to return, assign your response to
   variable inside ResponseBody and return it to caller of API function.

   ```
   public ParallelFlux<ResponseBody> convertListToMap() {
                 //created list of string str

               return Flux.fromIterable(str)
                       .parallel(3)
                       .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                       .map( s -> {
                   //some logic here
               });
          }



    Flux<String> responsePost = webClient.build()
                               //removed get,url and retrieve here                             
                               .bodyToFlux(ResponseBody.class);
   ```